# Link a footer text in CGridView, Yii 1.1.15

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have a CGridView, one particular column is CLinkColumn. The footer for this column presently appears in plain text, I need it to be hyperlinked as well.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$provider_sales,
        'columns'=>array(
            ...,
            array(                    
                'header'=>'Status',
                'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
                'urlExpression'=>function($data){ return ...},
                'footer'=>  number_format($totals['status']),
            ),
        ),
));
```

How do I convert it to a hyperlink?
Now I just need one footer item to hyperlink, this could change tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can simply use this `CHtml::link` in `footer`

```
 'footer'=> CHtml::link(number_format($totals['status']),Yii::app()->createUrl("Your_Url"),array("target"=>"_blank")),
```

You can also pass `param` in this

```
CHtml::link('Link Text',array('controller/action',
                                         'param1'=>'value1'));
```

For more info please read http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh0